# Troubleshooting axios requests

Tags: javascript, axios, request-headers

I've come across this problem a few times now and I feel like there's someone out there who knows a better way to troubleshoot api calls than i - specifically request headers.

Often when i need to pass my api token via a request header, I am constantly groping at the exact format to pass my key's (it seems there's not a universal format for doing this).

For example, I am currently trying to access the vultr v1 api. The docs give a curl example where `API-Key: SOMEKEY` needs to be passed, yet, my first attempt rarely works then i'm just groping... Do they want my key in a key/value pair or a single string in an array? Do i use es6 objects (without quotes) or not.

here's what i mean:

```
// one method 
const opts = {
  headers: {
    API-Key: 'SOMEKEY'
  }
}
// another
const opts = {
  'headers': {
    'API-Key': 'SOMEKEY'
  }
}
// another
const opts = {
  headers: [
    'API-Key: SOMEKEY'
  ]
}

axios.get(url, opts).then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

which is the proper way? In the curl example given by vultr it shows:
`curl -H 'API-Key: EXAMPLE' https://api.vultr.com/v1/iso/list`

I also see in my network inspector that the request headers show i am passing my API key yet i am still getting a 403 (bad key error)
[image: network inspector]

I have double checked the validity of my key and that's not the problem.
My question is this:
How do i find the correct format for the headers? Is there a better troubleshooting method for this kind of problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ya'll

UPDATE: 
Turns out they've got access control based on IP's. I hadn't noticed it till just now. They were blocking my request because of this. My question still stands however. Good methods for figuring out correct formats? Is there a correct format?

Answer (score 0):

One way is setting Headers while creating axios object, as follows :

```
 axios = axios.create({headers: {'API-Key': 'EXAMPLE'}});
 axios.get(url, opts).then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

Or

```
axios.get(url, {headers: {'API-Key': 'EXAMPLE'}}).then(res => console.log(res.data))
```